# Invalid hook call ERROR if I try to use hooks in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have one functional component with

```
import facebookLogin from '../functions/facebookLogin';

function NetworksList(props) {

    const getUserInfo = () => {
        console.log('beforeError')
        console.log(facebookLogin())
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.NetworksList}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={getUserInfo}>
                <Text style={styles.whiteTitle}>PushToFB</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
```

and the next one

```
function facebookLogin() {

  const [user, setUser] = useState(0)

  return (
    <>
        Hello, world
    </>
  )
}

export default facebookLogin;
```

and after I push to "PushToFB" text I see an error:

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem., js engine: hermes

I checked versions of React, hope, wright read rules of hooks, reinstalled npm.

Comment: You can't use hooks inside functions. Also, your hook seems to be a component. Why do you call it instead of rendering?

Comment: I think you're confused about this function. You're calling this function in your code, which supposed to do something when calling, but your function actually returns HTML content (or JSX).
Also, you can't use any React hook outside a React component.

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting means that you are trying to use a hook or a component in a way that is not allowed based on the "rules of hooks".

In this case there are a few problems:

- You are trying to call a React component as if it was a regular functions.
  So doing `facebookLogin()` is not something that would work.
- You are actually calling `facebookLogin()` within another function.
  And since `getUserInfo()` is not a React component nor a hook, you are breaking the mentioned rule - `Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

---

If I understand correctly and what you are trying to do is dynamically show the `facebookLogin` component upon the button click event, you'd usually want to use a state for that.

**For example:**

```
import facebookLogin from '../functions/facebookLogin';

function NetworksList(props) {
    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

    return (
        <View style={styles.NetworksList}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setIsVisible(true)}>
                <Text style={styles.whiteTitle}>PushToFB</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            { /* Only render the component if the value of `isVisible` is `true` */ }
            {isVisible && <facebookLogin />}
        </View>
    )
}
```

You could also use the button to toggle between open and closed states, instead of only opening, if you write something like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setIsVisible(prev => !prev)}>
```

---

P.S. - Use title case for React component names.
So instead of `facebookLogin`, it should be `FacebookLogin`.